# Ao navegar em telas de fragment e retornar, a tela fica branca

Tags: android, android-fragment

tenho na MainActivity 3(três) Fragments (HomeFragment, ChannelFragment e SearchFragment), com mudança feita através de tabs com clique apenas. Dentro da HomeFragment tenho mais 2(dois) Fragments (VideosFragment e PlaylistFragment), este com mudança no clique e tbm com um view pager.

Funcionou, mas um problema surgiu depois que adicionei estas duas últimas fragments. Pois quando vou para a tela SearchFragment, está carrega legal, mas quando volto para a tela do início, a HomeFragment, esta aparece os tabs, mas fica toda branca, o conteúdo da VideoFragment e PlaylistFragment fica todo branco.

Chego a ver os logs, fazendo requisições, mas simplesmente nao aparece o conteúdo.

já tentei reecriar no onCreate, etc, sem sucesso.

Segue os métodos para melhor entendimento (MainActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
}

public void init() {
    initializeTabHost();
    initializeViewPager();
    hideShowKeyboards(false);
}

private void initializeViewPager() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragments.add(homeFragment);
    ChannelsListFragment channelsListFragment = new ChannelsListFragment();
    fragments.add(channelsListFragment);
    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment() {
    fragments.add(searchFragment);

    FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    viewPagerCustom = (ViewPagerCustom) super.findViewById(R.id.main_viewPagerCustom);
    viewPagerCustom.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    viewPagerCustom.addOnPageChangeListener(new PagerChangerListener());
}

 public void initializeTabHost() {
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    icHome = new ImageView(this);
    icHome.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home_clicked);
    icChannel = new ImageView(this);
    icChannel.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_channel);
    icSearch = new ImageView(this);
    icSearch.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);

    addTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1").setIndicator(icHome));
    addTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2").setIndicator(icChannel));
    addTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3").setIndicator(icSearch));
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHostChangeListener());
}
```

Métodos da HomeFragment:

```
public HomeFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null)
        return null;

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    init();
    Log.i("Ciclo", "onCreateView() sendo chamado HomeFragment");

    return rootView;
}

private void init() {
    initTabHost();
    initializeVariables();
    initializeViewPager();
}

private void initTabHost() {
    fragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    fragmentTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab 1").setIndicator("VÍDEOS"),
            VideosFragment.class, null);
    fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab 2").setIndicator("PLAYLISTS"),
            PlaylistFragment.class, null);

    fragmentTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener());

    fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.color.icomptv_blue);
    //fillColor();
    fillColorLine();

    //Personaliza texto tabHost
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) fragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tv.setTextSize(15);
    }
}

private void initializeViewPager() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    VideosFragment videosFragment = new VideosFragment();
    fragments.add(videosFragment);
    PlaylistFragment playlistFragment = new PlaylistFragment();
    fragments.add(playlistFragment);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragments);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new PagerChangerListener());
}
```

Oncreate da VideoFragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null)
        return null;

    Log.i("Ciclo", "onCreateView() do VideoFragment");
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);

    initMethods();

    return view;
}
```

Bom galera, quem puder me dizer o porquê desse erro? e propor uma solução agradeço

Comment: o método setOffsScreenPageLimit() chega até a funcionar quando coloco para 3 o parametro. mas para de aparece o conteúdo da search

Comment: posta o código do seu adapter por favor. E substitua essa linha: FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); 
por :  FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() , fragments);

Comment: Cara só mudei essa linha que falou e funcionou :D Obg, pode me explicar a diferença entre eles ??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() , fragments);
```

Fonte:

[aqui](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)